# Paypal SDK and Google Analytics SDK issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, google-analytics

I had google analytics implemented in my iOS app and it was working great, but then when i added the PayPal SDK it was giving me problems with the Paypal SDK that when I click the pay button I set for paypal it would cause the app to crash. I contacted Paypal about it and they said it was because of google analytics.

Here is my console log:

```
2013-11-29 12:46:34:426 Flattened[35545:1803] TestFlight: Crash Handlers are installed
2013-11-29 12:46:34.431 Flattened[35545:70b] Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2013-11-29 12:46:35.694 Flattened[35545:70b] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: , or invalid scale factor: 2.000000
2013-11-29 12:46:35.701 Flattened[35545:70b] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: , or invalid scale factor: 2.000000
2013-11-29 12:46:35.701 Flattened[35545:70b] Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.Aevidum.Aevidum"
2013-11-29 12:46:35:824 Flattened[35545:5635] TestFlight: Started Session
2013-11-29 12:46:35.854 Flattened[35545:70b] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002
2013-11-29 12:46:35.856 Flattened[35545:70b] iRate did not prompt for rating because the app was first used less than 5 days ago
2013-11-29 12:46:35.856 Flattened[35545:821b] iRate is checking http://itunes.apple.com/US/lookup?bundleId=com.Aevidum.Aevidum to retrieve the App Store details...
2013-11-29 12:46:35.860 Flattened[35545:821b] iRate could not find the App Store ID for this application. If the application is not intended for App Store release then you must specify a custom ratingsURL.
2013-11-29 12:46:35.861 Flattened[35545:821b] iRate could not find your app on iTunes. If your app is not yet on the store or is not intended for App Store release then don't worry about this
2013-11-29 12:46:35.938 Flattened[35545:70b] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAITrackedViewController viewDidAppear:] (GAITrackedViewController.m:21): Tracked view controller missing view name.
2013-11-29 12:46:36:290 Flattened[35545:5635] TestFlight: App Token is recognized
2013-11-29 12:46:39.066 Flattened[35545:3903] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher hitsForDispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:271): No pending hits.
2013-11-29 12:46:39.303 Flattened[35545:70b] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: , or invalid scale factor: 2.000000
2013-11-29 12:46:39.304 Flattened[35545:70b] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAITrackedViewController viewDidAppear:] (GAITrackedViewController.m:21): Tracked view controller missing view name.
2013-11-29 12:46:39.476 Flattened[35545:3903] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:414): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_u" = ".etno";
        "&_v" = "mi3.0.1";
        "&an" = Aevidum;
        "&av" = "1.0";
        "&cd" = Paypal;
        "&cid" = "9afcd97f-5d04-4d56-98cf-f7aef7265f4a";
        "&sr" = 320x568;
        "&t" = appview;
        "&tid" = "UA-26097567-5";
        "&ul" = en;
        "&v" = 1;
        "&z" = 17610973406005460164;
        gaiVersion = "3.01";
    };
    timestamp = "2013-11-29 17:46:39 +0000";
}
2013-11-29 12:46:40.657 Flattened[35545:70b] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <UINavigationController: 0xd19bf90>.
2013-11-29 12:46:40.707 Flattened[35545:70b] -[UICTFont set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd2c7920
2013-11-29 12:46:40.714 Flattened[35545:70b] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:49): Uncaught exception: -[UICTFont set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd2c7920
2013-11-29 12:46:40.716 Flattened[35545:3903] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:414): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_u" = ".o";
        "&_v" = "mi3.0.1";
        "&an" = Aevidum;
        "&av" = "1.0";
        "&cd" = Paypal;
        "&cid" = "9afcd97f-5d04-4d56-98cf-f7aef7265f4a";
        "&exd" = "NSInvalidArgumentException\nTrace:\n-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]\n___forwarding___\n_CF_forwarding_prep_0\n__NSStringDrawingEngine\n-[NSA";
        "&exf" = 1;
        "&sr" = 320x568;
        "&t" = exception;
        "&tid" = "UA-26097567-5";
        "&ul" = en;
        "&v" = 1;
        "&z" = 17610973406005460165;
        gaiVersion = "3.01";
    };
    timestamp = "2013-11-29 17:46:40 +0000";
}
2013-11-29 12:46:40.717 Flattened[35545:3903] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:175): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
2013-11-29 12:46:40.717 Flattened[35545:3903] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:499): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?av=1.0&cd=Paypal&t=appview&ul=en&_u=.etno&tid=UA-26097567-5&cid=9afcd97f-5d04-4d56-98cf-f7aef7265f4a&v=1&sr=320x568&_v=mi3.0.1&an=Aevidum&ht=1385747199472&qt=1245&z=17610973406005460164
2013-11-29 12:46:40.937 Flattened[35545:70b] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:157): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
2013-11-29 12:46:40.937 Flattened[35545:3903] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:426): hit(s) Successfully dispatched
2013-11-29 12:46:40.939 Flattened[35545:3903] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:167): 1 hit(s) sent
2013-11-29 12:46:40.940 Flattened[35545:3903] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:175): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
2013-11-29 12:46:40.940 Flattened[35545:3903] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:499): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?exf=1&av=1.0&cd=Paypal&t=exception&ul=en&_u=.o&tid=UA-26097567-5&exd=NSInvalidArgumentException%0ATrace%3A%0A-%5BNSObject%28NSObject%29+doesNotRecognizeSelector%3A%5D%0A___forwarding___%0A_CF_forwarding_prep_0%0A__NSStringDrawingEngine%0A-%5BNSA&sr=320x568&cid=9afcd97f-5d04-4d56-98cf-f7aef7265f4a&v=1&an=Aevidum&_v=mi3.0.1&ht=1385747200714&qt=225&z=17610973406005460165
2013-11-29 12:46:40.995 Flattened[35545:70b] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:157): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
2013-11-29 12:46:40.996 Flattened[35545:3903] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:426): hit(s) Successfully dispatched
2013-11-29 12:46:40.997 Flattened[35545:3903] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:167): 1 hit(s) sent
2013-11-29 12:46:46.743 Flattened[35545:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICTFont set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd2c7920'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x038cb5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0364e8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03968903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x038bb90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x038bb4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIFoundation                        0x055b32e5 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 26061
    6   UIFoundation                        0x055b38ac -[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:context:] + 610
    7   UIKit                               0x02993a1c -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 5576
    8   UIKit                               0x02991b94 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 577
    9   UIKit                               0x02993b0e -[UILabel drawRect:] + 98
    10  UIKit                               0x0284bd56 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 504
    11  QuartzCore                          0x024a9dc9 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 123
    12  QuartzCore                          0x024a9cfa _ZL16backing_callbackP9CGContextPv + 96
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0239acf4 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2656
    14  QuartzCore                          0x024a9c92 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 93
    15  QuartzCore                          0x024ddb23 x_blame_allocations + 15
    16  QuartzCore                          0x024a9afd _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1519
    17  QuartzCore                          0x024a9d49 -[CALayer _display] + 33
    18  QuartzCore                          0x024a9506 _ZN2CA5Layer7displayEv + 144
    19  QuartzCore                          0x024a9d23 -[CALayer display] + 33
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0249ded3 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 323
    21  QuartzCore                          0x0249df4c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 38
    22  QuartzCore                          0x02405ae6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    23  QuartzCore                          0x02406e71 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    24  QuartzCore                          0x02407544 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x038934ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0389341f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x03871344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x03870ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x038708db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x042ea9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x042ea809 GSEventRun + 104
    32  UIKit                               0x027e1d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    33  Flattened                           0x000b436d main + 141
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x03e3c70d start + 1
    35  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling UIFont set somewhere in your code ? Since that's where the crash is coming from

```
2013-11-29 16:58:26.526 Flattened[45428:70b] -[UICTFont set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd1b9970
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an instance of `UICTFont` is being prematurely released. Check your memory management! Static analyzer results are a good place to start.