# GoogleAnalytics 3.14 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *)

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics

I have used google analytics and faced with the problem:

Standard initialisation:

```
GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;  // report uncaught exceptions
gai.logger.logLevel = kGAILogLevelVerbose;  // remove before app release
self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance]trackerWithTrackingId:getGooglTrackingId()];
```

After it i have an error:
[clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xziDN.png)

I find similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291156/paypal-sdk-and-google-analytics-sdk-issue), however it does not help me (

Also if i use same code and SDK in another project it works fine.

Already spend 2 days to resolve it. Please help.